# Limit number of bootstrap cards in a div

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a function in react that returns a bootstrap card, and a div that those cards get mapped to, however I only want 4 of those cards per row, but they tend to squeeze so much to the point where its 10 cards per row, is there a way to limit the number of card columns in a row for a single div??

Comment: Post some of your code so we can help. Post the html and css that accompanies it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Give the card a fixed width of 250px(or any fixed width) ...
i.e
In a css file;

```
.card {
  width:250px;
}
```

OR

```
.card {
 max-width:250px;
 min-width:250px;
}
```

In a html file;

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="card">
 </div>
</div>
```